# How to measure gaps inside text block when work whith PSD template

Tags: css, photoshop, font-size

For example:
I have PSD mockup I try to do site pixel to pixel.When I try to measure position between blocks - it's ok, I got right dimension.
But if I do it for text blocks - I got dimension from top of text to other blocks, and I got wrong dimension margin when I use it in my styles.
How to cope with it?

Answer (score 0):

When you measure the distance between a 'block' and a 'text block' you are probably not taking into account the line-height of the text.

The text block will actually have some additional space above and below depending on the size of the line-height ('leading' in photoshop) which makes it much harder to get a definite measurement.

I am not sure if there is a simple solution for this but I would recommend using a Chrome Plugin called [PerfectPixel](http://www.welldonecode.com/perfectpixel/). It is a very helpful tool if you want to get a pixel precise result.